# Why does fft energy leakage was solved

Tags: fft

if we take a sinus with Fd=100KHz with fs=1000KHz sampling rate We do an FFT with 256 members we get energy leakage.
Why choosing Fd=113.28Khz solves this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here on how to work with the units in question:

[DFT exercise in the book Understanding digital signal processing 3 Ed](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69186/dft-exercise-in-the-book-understanding-digital-signal-processing-3-ed/69233#69233)

Then apply the fact that leakage does not occur when the DFT frame covers a whole number of cycles of your tone signal.

---

$$ Fs = 1000000 \frac{Samples}{Second}  $$

$$ Fd = 113280  \frac{Cycles}{Second} $$

$$ N = 256 \frac{Samples}{Frame} $$

$$ \frac{Fd}{Fs} \cdot N = \frac{\frac{Cycles}{Second}}{\frac{Samples}{Second}} \cdot \frac{Samples}{Frame} = \frac{Cycles}{Frame}  $$

$$ \frac{113280}{1000000} \cdot 256 =  28.99968 $$

Which is pretty darn close to a whole number.

Comment: we have a range of 1000KHz which is divided by 256,so each bin is 3.90625KHz.
(113.28Khz/256)*1000K