# Indexing in DFT (from an old paper)

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft

There is a nice paper on explaining DFT from the 1960s in IEEE [A guided tour of the fast Fourier transform](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5213896). The author uses the following definitions of DFT

DFT
$$
X(j)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x(k) \exp \left(-i 2 \pi\left(\frac{j}{N}\right) k\right)
$$

Inverse
$$
x(k)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} X(j) \exp \left(i 2 \pi\left(\frac{j}{N}\right) k\right)
$$

where the indexes *j* = 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1 and similarly *k*=0, 1, 2,..., N-1.

Now the authors show a figure, where the **j and k indices run from 0 to N not N-1**. Let us say we had 10 data points, so N=10; and *j* and *k* should run from 0 to 9 not 10. Is this a typographical error in the figure?

It seems that his *N* also starts from zero, then the figure is consistent but the summation formula has N-1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figures are correct. You can see that there are samples at indices $0,1,\ldots,N-1$. There are no samples shown at index $N$, neither in the time domain nor in the frequency domain. The value $N$ is only shown on the abscissa because in the frequency domain it corresponds to the sampling frequency, and in the time domain it corresponds to the end of the continuous-time signal represented by $N$ samples (if we assume that each sample represents a portion of length $\Delta T$).

For a very detailed discussion on the definition of the actual duration of a discrete-time sequence have a look at the answers to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/71181/4298).

Comment: Thanks for the link. With specific ref. to the figure, you mean the last vertical line in the figure refers to k= N-1 in the time domain and j=N-1 in the frequency domain? My field is chemistry and I wanted to use DFT for deconvolution, hence looking at some fundamental early papers for self-teaching.

Comment: @M.Farooq: Yes, the last vertical line in both plots is clearly not at index $N$ but at $N-1$.

Comment: and the *"first"* vertical line is clearly at index $0$.  some of us like to call that the *"zeroth"* vertical line.